# Pandas Comparing column with another list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
item1 = {'category':'food::cafe::restaurant::business', 'name':'Bob Cafe'}
item2 = {'category':'food::take away::restaurant::business', 'name':'John Take Away'}
item3 = {'category':'cafeteria::business', 'name':'Annie Cafe'}
item4 = {'category':'hotel::business', 'name':'Premier Inn'}
df = pd.DataFrame([item1, item2, item3, item4])
lookup_table = ['cafe', 'cafeteria', 'restaurant']
```

I want to create a new column in the DF (Yes/No) that matches the category column with the lookup_table. The category column needs to be split by '::' to get individual categories and compare this against the different values in the list. In the above example, everything other than item4 should be True.

I dont want to loop through every single item in the df.category column and check if its present in the table. I'm relatively new to python....so more than the solution, I'm keen on the thought process for solving this the "python" way.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
`str.contains`

```
m = df.category.str.contains('|'.join(lookup_table))
df['Yes/No'] = np.where(m, 'Yes', 'No')

df    
                                category            name Yes/No
0       food::cafe::restaurant::business        Bob Cafe    Yes
1  food::take away::restaurant::business  John Take Away    Yes
2                    cafeteria::business      Annie Cafe    Yes
3                        hotel::business     Premier Inn     No
```

Just pass a "regex pattern" formed by the piping of each string in `lookup_table` to `str.contains`. A mask is then returned (based on whether any of the categories were matched in the row). This mask is converted to `Yes`/`No` answers using `np.where`.

---

**Option 2**
`str.split` + `isin` + `any`

```
m = df.category.str.split('::', expand=True).isin(lookup_table).any(1)
df['Yes/No'] = np.where(m, 'Yes', 'No')

df    
                                category            name Yes/No
0       food::cafe::restaurant::business        Bob Cafe    Yes
1  food::take away::restaurant::business  John Take Away    Yes
2                    cafeteria::business      Annie Cafe    Yes
3                        hotel::business     Premier Inn     No
```

Similar to the option above, but this is pure string matching, not regex matching. Taking advantage of your data to split on `::` (double colons) which results in a dataframe looking like this -

```
i = df.category.str.split('::', expand=True)
i
           0          1           2         3
0       food       cafe  restaurant  business
1       food  take away  restaurant  business
2  cafeteria   business        None      None
3      hotel   business        None      None
```

Now, call `df.isin`, performing a "is equals?" check against each string in `lookup_table`. This results in -

```
j = i.isin(lookup_table)

      0      1      2      3
0  False   True   True  False
1  False  False   True  False
2   True  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False
```

The next step is to find *which* rows have this category in *any* column... so... use `any`.

```
j.any(axis=1)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

As before, this mask is converted to `Yes`/`No` answers using `np.where`, but there are other ways to do so (such as `replace`/`str.replace`).

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
%%timeit
m = df.category.str.contains('|'.join(lookup_table))
np.where(m, 'Yes', 'No')

1 loop, best of 3: 536 ms per loop
```

```
%%timeit 
m = df.category.str.split('::', expand=True).isin(lookup_table).any(1)
df['Yes/No'] = np.where(m, 'Yes', 'No')

1 loop, best of 3: 2.31 s per loop
```

Results may vary for your data, and for the number of items in `lookup_table`.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks a lot coldspeed. Makes you appreciate the language even more.

Comment: Forgot to mention, my data set is huge (>20mn rows).....any comments on performance against such a large dataset for the 2 options?

Comment: @user2097496 good question. The answer would differ based on your data, but I'm willing to bet the first option is more _efficient_, because it doesn't expand your column as the second one would. If you're interested, I'll create some test data and time it.

Comment: @user2097496 The first option is by far the better one, more efficient for larger dataframes.